# How to add GWTQuery to an existing Vaadin Project?

Tags: jquery, gwt, vaadin, gwtquery

I am new to Vaadin and GWT but i'm an advanced javascript Programmer. Now im working on a Vaadin existing Project and want to use the great possibilities of jQuery into my Project... how can i add GWTQuery into an existing Vaadin Project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.- If you are using maven add these lines to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.googlecode.gwtquery</groupId>
 <artifactId>gwtquery</artifactId>
 <version>1.2.0</version>
 <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Otherwise download gwtquery-1.2.0.jar from the project site and include it in your classpath

2.- Add this line to `your_application.gwt.xml` file:

```
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.query.Query'/>
```

3.- Import statically methods from the `GQuery` class

```
import static com.google.gwt.query.client.GQuery.*;
```

4.- Use it to enhance your dom or widgets

```
$("css_selector").css("width", "100%");
$("css_selector", my_widget).hide();
```

5.- Be aware that you cannot use jquery plugins, but you can use the core api of jquery (with some differences). There are many gquery plugins though.

Comment: oh yes!! i use maven too. So its there no possibility to use jquery plugins like this : http://www.datatables.net/ for example??

Comment: You would need to wrap then in jsni code import the jquery js files. It would not use gquery and get the benefit of gwt optimization.

Comment: @trouble: you cannot use jquery plugins with gquery, gquery is an entire implementation of the jquery api in java, so those methods aren't available in js. I'm working on gquery and gwt-exporter to  export those methods and many other hacks to support jquery plugins, take a look to http://gquery.org/wiki/JsQuery

Comment: @SachinShekharR: be aware that you cannot copy and paste js fragments without reviewing carefully that code. i.e: you have to redefine window, document with $wnd, $doc. Anyway, to import a jquery plugin you have to import jquery as well and prolly it could not be embedded in jsni specially if you use the new gwt closure optimization.

Comment: @trouble: CellTable and DataGrid (http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable) in GWT are very convenient, you should consider them as the alternative to datatables.net

Comment: Indeed. Trying use  jquery plugin code would mean large effort on sanity check and also a large effort for security checks. No gwt unit test cases either!!

Comment: All in one that's mean! actually a smooth integration of jquery plugins with GWT in any way is possible?

Comment: You can use jquery plugins in gwt (as any other 3-party javascript) but you have to code jsni wrappers to call their methods. In the case of jquery plugins you have to include in your .html the tags to load the script as well as jquery. You could avoid including jquery if you expose gwtquery methods (see http://gquery.org/wiki/JsQuery), but this is very experimental. Another option is to port the plugin to gquery (see http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/WritingPlugins).

Answer (score 1):

Same as you would for any other GWT project:

1. Place the GWTQuery JAR under a folder on your project's path (it is not necessary to locate it under `WEB-INF/lib`, as it is not required during runtime).
2. Include it in the build path for your project (e.g. in eclipse - right click the JAR file and select ***Build Path > Add To Build Path***).
3. Add a corresponding entry in the module xml:

   ```xml
   <inherits name="com.google.gwt.query.Query" />
   ```

Be sure to run the GWT compiler before running in production mode.

**Further Reading:**
*[Organizing Projects](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/1.6/DevGuideOrganizingProjects)* on the Google Developers' GWT docs.

Comment: Don't forget the `inherits` statement.